# what is this load center amperage total?

Tags: electrical

Yesterday I took a picture but forgot to took the info plate for amperage rating on it. [image]

My main question: Is there a way to calculate the total amperage that load center currently has?

Extra question: Can you also  calculate the amperage rating by looking at it also?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this the easiest way to gauge service size is simply looking at the main breaker. Keep in mind, every part of the service; riser, meter pan, entrance cable, etc...must be sized and rated for the service size.

In this case it looks like a 200A service. What you have there is a 200A, 20/40 main breaker panel. 20 full size spaces that can all accept twin, or tandem, breakers.

Not sure what you mean by what amperage the service "has". You can tell the service size like I explained, and you can tell what the load is at one pin pint in time by using a clamp-on amp meter.

You can tell what the calculated load is by doing a load calculation on your home, although this is not an accurate number of actual draw. Here is one example: http://www.nojolt.com/load_calculations.shtml
You can do a web search for lots of info on load calculations.

Bear in mind, adding up the breakers in the panel is a completely meaningless number and will NOT give any kind of assessment of load. It is not uncommon to see 600-800 amps worth of breakers in a 200A panel.

Comment: How can you tell that it's 200 amp service?

Comment: @Tester101, Experience. From the size/shape of the main breaker and the size of the entrance conductors. Seen a million of them.

Comment: I agree it looks like 200  + to speedy good answer on total load

Comment: @Kris, I understand what and why he was asking. This is why I said _"In this case **it looks like** a 200A service"._ ..............Again, from experience I can tell for 99% certainty that that wire is 4/0AL.

Comment: @Kris, 4/0AL is the typical size for a 200A service to a dwelling. Check your code book again.

Comment: @Kris, where do you see that requirement for dwelling services??

Comment: @SpeedyPetey 338.10 describes the problem when SE wires are ran inside a dwelling.  The thermal rating is dropped to 60° if covered by thermal insulation.

Comment: Not for a dwelling. T310.15(B)(7) trumps this. How can you derate the conductor by temperature when temperature is not a consideration in the first place. 310.15(B)(7) says nothing about following 338.10 or derating for insulation, temperature or otherwise.

Comment: @Kris, I'm not sure what your authority on this is, but I am not mistaken. In almost 30 years in the trade this is first time I have ever heard this interpretation of yours. Obviously I am not alone in my thinking. Maybe this is a local interpretation, but it certainly is not widespread thinking.

Comment: Since T310.15(B)(7) has ampacities lower than typical, what do you base the 60 deg C ampacites on?? Please don't tell me 310.15. If so then what's the point of T310.15(B)(7)?

Comment: This is nothing new. See [link](http://forums.mikeholt.com/showthread.php?t=119626)

Comment: Not really. You found a couple of old threads on Mike Holt, which I only frequent once in a while so no, I didn't see them. That does not make it old news or a popular issue. I have also moderated an electrical forum since 2007 and from my recollection this has never come up.
No, in all my years this has never come up, least of all from an inspector. And I have done hundreds of 200A services. ........... I will also say I 100% disagree with the interpretation that 338.10 completely negates T310.15(B)(7). The notion is absurd.

Comment: 338.10 only negates 310.15(B)(7) when the conductors are ran in a SE type wire AND are covered in thermal insulation.  It is not that complicated.

Comment: I am far from "spouting" anything, I am just conveying how long that this has not ever come up. And I am not ignoring your "enlightenment" (hahaha). I am simply standing by my interpretation and will continue to do so.